# Como volver al Intent anterior - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin

Necesito volver al `Intent` anterior, sin llamarlo como un nuevo Intent. `Xamarin Android App`

Como lo puedo hacer?

Tengo en el `MainLayout` un boton para buscar libros, ese boton me redirige a `ClaseBuscar.cs` y al `Layout Busqueda`, ese Layout muestra según lo que digite el cliente los resultados en un RecyclerView, y luego al hacer click en uno de esos resultados me redirige a otro Layout donde me muestra el libro; esto funciona muy bien.

La cosa esta en que ahora tengo también en `MainLayout` un campo en el que puedes reservar el libro que vas a leer después y se necesita reutilizar el proceso de `Layout Busqueda` para evitar que digiten libros falsos, pero al hacer el proceso anterior nuevamente con `Buscar.cs` una vez seleccionado un resultado tenemos que volver al Intent anterior (MainLayout) pero sin tener que recargarlo como un nuevo Intent.

He intentado con:

```
Finish();
```

**Pero solo me funciona si la ejecuto en el Main. Si ya lo uso en otra clase no me funciona. Lo revise paso a paso y simplemente ejecuta la linea y luego no pasa nada. Se queda en el Layout como si tal no tuviera esa linea de codigo.**

Solo me funciona como lo necesito si uso la flecha (el botón volver) del dispositivo.

Lo he intentado también con `Start Activity For Result` como en la foto pero en `PROSPECTOS` (Activity 2), al llegar al final:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.PutExtra("result", gNombredeTema);
SetResult(Result.Ok, returnIntent);
Finish();
```

Solo ejecuta pero no finaliza el `Activity`.
[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Y que pasa si llamas a onDestroy().

Comment: @DanielBriceño. ----- OnDestroy(); ----- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Application.dispatchActivityDestroyed(android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference. ------

Comment: I do not speak English.  But if I can translate with google translator.  Please communicate in Spanish which would help me a lot.

Comment: Lo escribo en español porque quiero asegurarme que es lo que te digo. Me parese interesante tu problema. Tus sintomas son como si la actividad no le funcionara el metodo de destruccion.... Me gustaria ver el manisfesto. No se si haga la diferencia pero me gustaria verlo.

Comment: @DanielBriceño te refieres al stack de salida? Es este: ( Extracto al ejecutar la linea Finish(); ) ----------  02-05 12:42:03.191 D/Mono    ( 8815): Assembly Ref addref PersonalA[0xe56f76c0] -> System.Core[0xe624ffe0]: 7
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
El subproceso 0x5 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16

Comment: Veo que ya no quieres darme mas informacion. Te deseo suerte y que resuelva tu problema. Gracias por su antencion.

Comment: Es que no hay mas información por compartir. Es básicamente un proyecto limpio donde necesito volver al intent de inicio, y el código ya esta en el post. No hay mas codigo que ese.

Comment: .¿Lo lograste?.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Si. No se si era que la creación del intent hacia que entrara en otro thread o que, pero la solución que me sirvió fue poner un Btn en el Layout B (prospectos) (botón que solo esta visible cuando es un intent de SetResult), y ese botón tiene el statement Finish(); para una vez seleccionado el tema poder continuar con el flujo anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es regresar a la `Activity` anteriormente cargada pero  "No quiero que el cliente le tenga que dar en la flecha de "Volver".", en este caso la única opción es llamar el método:

> Finish();

pero mencionas que no funciona, **recuerda que si te encuentras dentro de un Fragment es necesario usar la Activity que contiene el Fragment como contexto para llamar `Finish()`;**

> Activity.Finish();

Para de esta forma eliminar la `Activity` actual y mostrar la anterior ya que no hay forma de iniciar una actividad desde otra sin usar un `Intent`.

Comment: No funciona Finish

Comment: Finish() la estas llamando desde un Fragment? si es un Fragment usa : Activity.Finish();

Comment: No, no estoy usando Fragments

Comment: No se si era que la creación del intent hacia que entrara en otro thread o que, pero la solución que me sirvió fue poner un Btn en el Layout B (prospectos) (botón que solo esta visible cuando es un intent de SetResult), y ese botón tiene el statement Finish(); para una vez seleccionado el tema poder continuar con el flujo anterior.